# Posting Through Angular to ExpressJS Backend Results in Weird Body Formatting

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to do a simple todo list application to learn angular as a frontend with express as the backend, the database is managed with sequelize. Posting to the node backend to add a user results in this object format  `{ '{"first_name":"132","last_name":"132","email":"123"}': '' }`

I cannot find any way to parse this or change the way the data is being sent.

Here is the relevant code:

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError as observableThrowError,  Observable } from 
'rxjs';

import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { User } from '../user';
import { catchError, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  url = "http://localhost:3000";
  private  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  });

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.url + '/users');
  }

  getUser(id: number): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.url + '/users/' + id);
  }

  addUser(user: User): Observable<User[]> {
    const body = {
      first_name: user.first_name,
      last_name: user.last_name,
      email: user.email
    }
    return this.http.post<User[]>(this.url + '/adduser', body, { headers: this.headers, responseType: 'json'}).pipe(
      catchError(response => { return observableThrowError(response); }));;
  }

}
```

index.js (the route)

```
router.post('/adduser', /*cors(corsOptions),*/ function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var firstName = req.body.first_name,
        lastName = req.body.last_name,
        email = req.body.email;
    models.User.create({
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
        email: email
    }).then(function() {
        res.send(200);
    })
});
```

Comment: You're sending JSON, but you've set the Content-Type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpParams documented [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

```
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { ... }
...
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append("page", 1);
....
this.httpClient.get<any>(apiUrl, {params: params});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code as suggested by user184994

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError as observableThrowError,  Observable } from 
'rxjs';

import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { User } from '../user';
import { catchError, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  url = "http://localhost:3000";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.url + '/users');
  }

  getUser(id: number): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.url + '/users/' + id);
  }

  addUser(user: User): Observable<User[]> {
    const body = {
      first_name: user.first_name,
      last_name: user.last_name,
      email: user.email
    }
    return this.http.post<User[]>(this.url + '/adduser', body).pipe(
      catchError(response => { return observableThrowError(response); }));;
  }

}
```